# OSM data download very big

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to download the OSM data for the province of Utrecht, the Netherlands. I'm following the steps as prescripted in the training manual, 7.2.4.. 
I have already loaded the provincial roads shapefile from here: http://www.nationaalgeoregister.nl/geonetwork/srv/dut/catalog.search#/metadata/fff94270-b5ce-4ed9-ae99-5f96096ac08d?tab=relations
So, that should give the right area I think. The coordinates given by the default are 4.76286-5.60752, 52.3291-51.8564. I figured those might be wrong or too big, but using google maps to find coordinates very similar to those. The OSM file exceeds 1GB, is there a way to see what exactly I'm downloading and select from that?

Comment: Overpassturbo allows you to narrow down the downloaded data by choosing what type of feature and with which tag you want to download. Still, data can be rather large, since OSM contains like everything.

Comment: OSM can be large, indeed. However this feels a little bit too large. The shapefile offered by Geofabrik for the whole Netherlands is 1.5 GB large: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html

Comment: There are smaller extracts from and specifically Utrecht >> https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Utrecht/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [QuickOSM](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM) plugin for QGIS, you can select an extent and specify what kind of data to download. It also provides importing some osm file formats to QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To locate smaller extracts for town and cities you can use the service from

Extracts are every Friday (latest is the 6th April 2018)

[image]

https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Utrecht/

If this service provides useful please consider a donation to keep the service up and running.
https://www.bbbike.org/community.html